# C# Remake connection string on another computer

Tags: c#, connection-string

I need to move my school project from one computer to another. I pasted the folder with everything on the new one, made a backup of my DB to remake on the new computer, but I realize that the connection string was generated when I created my project and linked the DB.

How can I update my connection string so that it works on my new computer? What part of it do I need to change?

```
<connectionStrings><add name="ProjectPGBDEntities" connectionString="metadata=&quot;res://*/Model.projectPGBD EDM.csdl|res://*/Model.projectPGBD EDM.ssdl|res://*/Model.projectPGBD EDM.msl&quot;;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Delvau_JB;initial catalog=ProjectPGBD;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

For information, the DB and the project were both local, nothing going through the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to get a new connection string is to open up your notepad, save an empty file on the desktop with the `.udl` extension and then open it. From there, you'll be guided to configuration. After you're set up, right click on the `.udl` file and do `Edit`. You'll have your connection string there.